# htaccess rewrite using regex not working with a dash

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For my rewrite I have:

`RewriteRule ^game/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L]`

The URL being `game/counter-strike/` is returning a copy of index.php (meaning it's saying `game.php?game=$1` doesn't exist), but if I echo `$_GET['game']` there then it echos `counter-strike`.

It works if the game name is one word, like `mmorpg`, just not with the dash. Is there an obvious problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable `MultiViews` option by placing this line at top of your .htaccess and have your rule like this

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^game/([a-z0-9-]+)/$ game.php?game=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.
- `QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much. What exactly does it do? And what does QSA do? What should I be using to help my Google rankings?

Comment: Added some description for `QSA` and `MultiViews`.